# Modifying creation and edit date of nodes by using Views Bulk Operations

Tags: datetime, views

I use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) (with Views 7.x-3.x-dev) to modify my nodes. I need to edit the created and edited on dates of the nodes. I checked bulk operations field, but I couldn't find the related fields.

Is it possible to edit these dates with VBO?

Comment: Please specify which major version of Drupal you are using.

Comment: @kekkis sorry, i added as D 7.

Comment: you probably need to write your own action then ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [New action for Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16865/new-action-for-views-bulk-operations)